# Async IStringLocalizer - GetAllStrings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We have a custom implementation of *IStringLocazlizer* that Loads labels from our internal company CMS that exposes data via HTTP Rest interface.

We wanted to use NET Core built in locazlier but I do not like the *GetAllStrings* Sync method that will have to Block on Tasks to perfrom HTTP Call.

We have a cache obvioulsy but I do think that it does not seem right.

Any thoughts on that?

Example:

```
public IEnumerable<LocalizedString> GetAllStrings(bool includeParentCultures)
    {
        Task<CmsLabelsModel> task = pipeline.SendAsync(new GetLabelsModelRequest(ResourceName));

        CmsLabelsModel result = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); //Yuk Yuk

        return result.LabelModels.Select(pair => new LocalizedString(pair.Key, pair.Value.Value));
    }
```

Comment: I think `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is the only option. Will the resouce change frequently in `CMS`? if not, you may consider register custom StringLocalizer as `Singleton` to improve performance.